# Parsing JSON Object using GSON and updating the JSON file (Search and Update)

Tags: json, gson, jsonpath

Below is my JSON Object

```
{
    "Germany": {
        "Languages": [
            "German",
            "English",
            "Austrian German"
        ],
        "Continent": "unknown",
        "Capital": "Berlin"
    },
    "China": {
        "Language": [
            "Standard Mandarin",
            "Cantenese",
            "English"
        ],
        "Continent": "Asia",
        "Capital": "Shanghai"
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to search for a keyword [Eg: Germany] if it exists, then update the attribute `Continent` from `unknown` to `Europe`.

How would we achieve this using GSON?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to update the continent if the condition is satisfied (i.e. Continent of Germany is "unknown" in input JSON).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"Germany\": {\"Languages\": [\"German\",\"English\",\"Austrian German\"],\"Continent\": \"unknown\",\"Capital\": \"Berlin\" }, \"China\": {\"Language\": [\"Standard Mandarin\",\"Cantenese\",\"English\"],\"Continent\": \"Asia\",\"Capital\": \"Shanghai\" }}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement countryJsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
    JsonElement germanyJsonElement = countryJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("Germany");

    boolean updatedFlag = false;

    if (germanyJsonElement != null) {
        if (germanyJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("Continent").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("unknown")) {
            germanyJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().remove("Continent");
            germanyJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("Continent", "Europe");
            updatedFlag = true;
        }
    }

    if (updatedFlag) {
        countryJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().remove("Germany");
        countryJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().add("Germany", germanyJsonElement);

        System.out.println("Germany continent updated....");
        System.out.println(countryJsonElement.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Germany continent not updated....");
    }

}
```

Comment: [
  {
    "applicationId": "email-id-1202",
    "extRefNumber": "targobank-ref-number2018-04-09T17:12:49.506",
    "bankName": "targobank",
    "applicants": [
      {
        "personId": "1",
        "documents": [
          {
            "fileId": "2",
            "documentId": "2",
            "type": "TAX_DOCUMENTS"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "data": {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "branchCode": "branch-code"
    }
  }
]

Comment: I have requirement to update type value, tried above code and couldn't achieve, can you please help